# How to handle Java Dates in any format?

Tags: java, javascript, sql

I want to save any date type format as user wishes: The date should be saved to the datebase in the format the user has entered (for example mm/dd/yy, dd/mm/yy or yy/dd/mm).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sure you want to do that?  A better solution would be to convert what users do into the one format that's consistent throughout the database.  I see no value at all in letting users dictate how their dates are rendered.

Comment: What day, month and year does 12/11/10 represent?

Comment: @Quentin Sept 4th, 1872. Duh.

Comment: Store the string as the user entered it. That will guarantee success. Just be sure to never try to interpret what that string means.

Comment: Really good answer is [there][1] it supports really lot of possible formats


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898250/java-program-to-accept-any-format-of-date-as-input-and-print-the-month

Comment: You need to store two pieces of information: the user's date format preference and the date. The date is stored as a date type in the db. User preferences are saved to the db and cached on the client. Presentation involving dates query the date value from the db and applies the cached date format. Don't mix presentation issues with data issues.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try it this way.

Store user preferred date format in his profile and all dates in some default format. When you want to show date to user format it according to his preferences like

```
String userFormat="yy/MM/dd";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(userFormat);

Date someDate = new Date();
String formatedDate = sdf.format(someDate);
System.out.println(formatedDate);
```

But thats just one of options.

Comment: +1 You should store dates in a standard format. Most databases have special field types for dates, and one of these should be used. Then when you display the date to the user, that's when to apply a custom format.